# Countdown in all screen flutter

Tags: flutter

I want a countdown widget on all screens.

Like when 1 screen countdown start
When a user switch to second screen countdown still working like you see in a test when one question is solved second question is show but they are in same screen in my case countdown start you can move different screens I don't know how i can handle it

Comment: How you are switching to new screen?

Comment: Use a global variable or a state management method, to share the count-down variable state to every screen?

Comment: I have 50+ screen do you have alternate

Answer (score 0):

in architecture

One way to do this would be to use a StatefulWidget and to have a method that you can call to start the countdown. In your State class, you can then have a Timer that will trigger every second and update the state accordingly.

Comment: I know this but when you change the screen your counter is on previous screen i have 50+ screens and user can move anywhere during this countdown